# A question about Euler characteristic in a space product

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a question about Euler characteristic.

Thing is that the Euler characteristic of the circumference $S^1$ es zero, that is $\mathcal{X}(S^1) = 0$, because we can consider $E = 1$ (all the circumference), $F = 0, V = 1$ (some chosen point).

Since a close interval $[a,b]$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ we get that Euler characteristic of $[0,1]$, for example, is also $0$.

And we know that $\mathcal{X}(M \times N) = \mathcal{X}(M)\mathcal{X}(N)$. So for the unity square $C = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ it would be $\mathcal{X}(C) = \mathcal{X}([0,1])\mathcal{X}([0,1]) = 0$.

But we know that $C$ has 4 vertices, 4 edges and 1 face: so $\mathcal{X}(C) = 4 + 1 - 4 = 1$. Then, what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: A closed interval is not homeomorphic to the circle. If you know that the Euler characteristic is a homeomorphism invariant, it provides a proof, as you suggest.

Comment: How it is possible that the interval [0,1] is homeomorphic to S^1?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I´m wrong, but I thought that since the "idea" is roll on $[0,1]$ to get $S^1$. EDIT: Ok, sorry. Actually, you can´t paste or cut to get homeomorphism. I mistake an example, thats all. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 3):

In order that this question actually gets an answer, the thing that is wrong - in line with Mike and Federico's comments - is that $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a variant of your calculation for the euler characteristic of $[0,1]^2$ *shows* that they are not homeomorphic!

Indeed, if $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, then they have the same euler characteristic.

Check by hand, that $\chi([0,1])=1$ by noting that there are two vertices ($0$-cells if you like) and $1$ edge so the Euler characteristic is $2 \cdot (-1)^0+(-1)^1=2-1=1$.

On  the other hand, $\chi(S^1)=0$ since it has one vertex and one edge.
This shows that they are not homeomorphic.

You can check by hand (as you did) that $\chi([0,1]^2)=1$ or by using the fact that $\chi([0,1]^2)=\chi([0,1] \cdot \chi ([0,1])=1 \cdot 1$.

The latter argument is nice since it implies that $\chi([0,1]^n)=1$ for any hypercube.

Comment: I note $\mathcal{X}([0,1]^3)$ is the cube.  And you have $\mathcal{X}(Cube) = 2$ (it´s  homeomorphic to $S^1$), so it can´t be 1. Yeah?

Comment: where did I write that? Why would $[0,1]^3$ be homeomorphic to $S^1$? the euler characteristic of $S^1$ is neither two nor one

Comment: Sorry, the sphere $S^2$ is homeomorphic to the cube, yeah? In same way $S^1$ is homeomorphic to a square (without interior). And you get $\mathcal{X}(Cube) = 1 \neq 2 = \mathcal{X}(S^2)$. Also, you have $\mathcal{X}(S^1) = 0 \neq 1 = \mathcal{X}(Square)$, no?

Comment: yeah that sounds right, so long as by "cube" and square" you mean the boundaries of $[0,1]^3$ and $[0,1]^2$ respectively.

Comment: In case there is further confusion, I think it is worth clarifying that Andres (in his answer) is talking about the "solid" cube, and "solid" square. These are not homeomorphic to $S^1$ and $S^2$ (as you assert in your comment above). The *boundaries* of those shapes, however, are homeomorphic to $S^2$ and $S^1$ respectively.

Comment: You´re right, Matt! Thanks!!!  :D

Comment: If you're satisfied that your question is answered, please either mark this answer or mine as the answer with the tick - then it no longer shows as unanswered on the site.